# Question regarding investigation in matrix items

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix and I wanna investigate a condition in each item of this. then I wanna delete any item that violates the condition and since It can affect on the following matrices, this index should be deleted on them also. for instance, consider the following matrix:

WS = array ([[[9.7764691 ],......[9.76139563],[8.93841915],[8.77505072]]])

we wanna check if any item in WS is greater than 9.0 , so the last two items should be deleted, thus

1. how we can write a code to **check** and **find** the values **lower** than 9 and
2. also **delete** them?

then we have another matrix that is related to the first one so since we have deleted some items on it we need to also **delete** items with the **same index** on **the second one**( for instance here are the last two items) :

array ([[[0.095], [0.085],...,...,[0.075]]])

3. how we can do this?

I really appreciate it if anybody answers me to write a code in NumPy or python to solve these problems

Answer (score 0):

You may find the solution below.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sun Nov 21 16:58:27 2021

@author: aytacbey
"""

WS = [9.7764691 ,7.91827167,9.81347291,9.76139563,8.93841915,8.77505072]
indexToBeDeleted=[]
arrayRelatedwithWS=[4,5,6,7,8,9] # exact same element number with WS
#Iterated by for loop for all items in the array
for i in range(len(WS)):
    #criteria for selecting the relevant indexes 
    if WS[i]<9:
        #getting the indexes which should be removed. 
        indexToBeDeleted.append(i)
        
#removing indexes from array 
#here it is important to start with the highest indexes due to the fact that 
#otherway will cause an offset which will effect the forthcoming indexes.        
for j in range(len(indexToBeDeleted)):
    #Delete process is executed starting with higher index
    WS.pop(indexToBeDeleted[abs(j-len(indexToBeDeleted)+1)])
    #same as array that is related with WS
    arrayRelatedwithWS.pop(indexToBeDeleted[abs(j-len(indexToBeDeleted)+1)])
print(WS)
print(arrayRelatedwithWS)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the response, the only thing that is not understandable for me is that why we should start with the highest indexes? I mean is not there any other solution to start it from the first indexes? I want to know that is it a rule or due to the current problem we wrote the code in this way....

Comment: You're welcome. It's because when we erase the lowest valued index, then the indexes that have higher values will be shifted, so there will be problems regarding that shift in index numbers. So it's fair to say that it depends on the situation.